# Add Bootstrap Carousel to magento page

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, magento, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried adding bootstrap carousel to my magento site and its working also but the problem is that i cant see the navigation arrows..

My code:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/FB_banner2.jpg"}}" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/FB_banner_1.jpg"}}" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/FB_banner_8.jpg"}}" alt="Flower" width="100%" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/FB_banner_12.jpg"}}" alt="Flower" width="100%" height="345">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

and my output is:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqBH2.jpg)

I want to add the arrows for left and right movement

Comment: Is that the complete code? if so you're missing some closing tags..

Comment: thats my complete code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the anchor tags for you previous and next buttons inside the caroucel wrapper.

View the example here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

try moving them inside / bottom of the wrapper:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <a>...</a>
   <a>...</a>
</div>
```

I think you're missing a couple of closing div tags after the link anchors.